# How to increment from a base value in mongodb and update many documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have an array of objects. Each is an object with a value index. When I update the value of an index on the client side to say 0. The mongo doc with the old index gets updated with the new index of 0 and the other docs get that index +1 - the same premise as splice.

Basically right now, I'm querying with the old index and storing the id to recall later.

Then I update all the other indexes by one.

I then set the old id to the new index. However, it's not working. It increments all the documents with 'index' wrong. I need it to increment 'index' from the actual value newIndex ++ for each following document.

Or... if there's another way I haven't seen.

```
    const {_id} = req.body.user;
    const { oldIndex, newIndex } = req.body.data;

    const keepIndex = await Tasks.find({_user: _id, index: oldIndex}).exec();

    const saveID = keepIndex[0]._id;
    let counter = newIndex;
    const updateIndexId = await Tasks.updateMany({_user: _id, index: {$gte : newIndex} }, {$inc : {'index' : 1} })
        .where('created_at')
        .gt(moment().startOf('day'))
        .lt(moment().endOf('day')).exec();

    const finalUpdate = await Tasks.updateOne({_id: saveID }, { $set : {'index': newIndex}}).exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... so I didn't go down this route. It proved way too difficult LOL.

Instead I got the state from the reducer and did an axios post request with the updated state. It's only updating indexes in the db anyway. Maybe not the best code :D

```
app.post('/api/update_task_index', async (req, res) => {
        req.body.items.map(async (x, index) => {
            Tasks.update({ _id: x._id }, { $set: { index: index } }).exec();
        });
});
```